# Switch WooCommerce FlexSlider from dots to thumbnails according to screen width

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to change the the WooCommerce FlexSlider to use dots when the screen width is less than 768 px and thumbnails when it is larger, instead of switching with deskop/mobile.

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'custom_update_woo_flexslider_options' );

function custom_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {
    $options['controlNav'] = wp_is_mobile() ? true : 'thumbnails';
    return $options;
}
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li img {
        display: none;
}
.flex-control-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2em;
    left: 30%;
      list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .35714rem;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
    border: solid #2d2d2d;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: 0 0;
    outline: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    opacity: .6;
}
.flex-control-paging li a, .flex-control-paging li a:before {
    height: 1.07143rem;
    width: 1.07143rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:before {
    display: block;
    transition: background .1s ease-out;
}

.flex-control-paging li a:before {
    background: #fff570;
    }}

/* Woocommerce Product Page Image Thumbnails Style */
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs {
justify-content: space-between;
display: flex; 
}
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I have tried to create an array so that I can show/hide dots or thumbnails with CSS:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'custom_update_woo_flexslider_options' );

function custom_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {
    // Set both options for controlNav
    $options['controlNav'] = array(
        true,
        'thumbnails',
    );

    return $options;
}
```

however when I do this the thumbnails are not visible, even though they are in the html